# How do I set the EditText Hint property without a resource?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have some text obtained from a database and would like to use it as a hint to one of our text fields. I found through googles that we can only set it using a Resource Id or via XML which again doesn't help. Unfortunately the trail ends quickly from here.

Does anyone know how to dynamically set the Hint property for a EditText?

Comment: What issue getting wen using `EditText.Hint = "Your text";`?

Comment: I'm such an idiot. I must've not been paying close enough attention. My first attempt I remember not being able to find it. Then again I could have been in the wrong project :-x Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use it as:

```
myEditText.setHint("This is hint");
```

Comment: This method is not available in Xamarin. The answer was simple. EditText.Hint = "Your text"; I wasn't paying close enough attention and missed it.

Comment: `EditText.Hint` is giving me staring results when using TextInputEditText.
It puts the text in the textbox, and disappears when I start typing. If I add the hint to the .axml file, and then use `EditText.Hint` I get both hits written over one another.

Comment: I tried adding the comment to the TextInputLayout instead, and it works as expected.